# Unable to use INDEX COUNT for referencing all of the rows in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use the format/formula `A:INDEX(B:B, COUNTA(A:A))` to reference all of the rows until the first empty one and it is not working.

If I skip the first row, then the formula works: `A2:INDEX(B2:B, COUNTA(A2:A))`.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe because you're using the number of rows to define the end of the data (using INDEX), you have to include a defined starting row. I think this should work for you:

```
=QUERY(A1:INDEX(B:B, COUNTA(A:A)), "SELECT *")
```

That is assuming you don't have data that exists beyond the first blank row.

Comment: AHHHHH. Oh wow. Yeah, that totally makes sense. Can't define an end if you don't define a start. Doh! Thanks!